# Trying to understand set theory? Subset vs Member?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm learning set theory and wanted to know if I'm understanding some of the basics correctly.  I have a feeling 1 and 2 are correct, but I'm not sure about 3 and 4.

```
Z = {1,3}
W = {1,2,3,4}
```

1) `Is Z ∈ W?` No, Z is not a member or W, because Z is the set {1,3}, while the members of W are 1,2,3,4.

2) `Is Z ⊆ W?` Yes, because all elements in the set Z (1 and 3) are also present in the set W.

3)`Is Z ∈ ℘(W)?` Yes, because ℘(W) is a set of sets, Z is a member of ℘(W) because {1, 3} is one of those sets.

4)`Is Z ⊆ ℘(W)?` No, Z is not a subset of the powerset of W because the elements in set Z (1 and 3) are not present in the set ℘(W).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all correct, except for the statement in 3) that "Z is a power set of ℘(W)" which should read "Z is an element of ℘(W)". Note that ℘(W) is called the *power set of W*.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo on my part. Is my statement now correct?

Comment: @ProgramGuy Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 6):

Looks good. Note that:
$$
Z \subseteq W \iff Z \in ℘(W)
$$
so statements $2$ and $3$ are equivalent.